# Зеркалирование почты Microsoft Exchange

Tags: windows-server, exchange

Добрый день.

Возможно кто-то сможет подсказать. Есть два сервера MS Exchange 2010 с одинаковым набором пользователей, но разными доменами, например `first.ru` и `second.ru`. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы все письма, приходящие на адреса `*@first.ru` так же копией отсылались на `*@second.ru`. Возможно ли это сделать как-нибудь глобально, не создавая транспортные/inbox правила для каждого отдельного пользователя?.. В `New-TransportRule` не нашёл возможности делать подстановки. Возможно есть ещё какой-то путь решения данной задачи?

Comment: У Вас это две независимые почтовые организации и разные леса доменов?

Comment: Два независимых леса на разных серверах. Оба - внешние друг для друга, но пользователи - одинаковые (по samAccountName и почтовому Alias) на обоих.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартными способами это сделать нельзя. Можно написать кучу транспортных правил, но их сложно будет обслуживать. Можно настроить пересылку почтовых сообщений на уровне почтового ящика, это можно даже автоматизировать, но Вы этого не хотите. Так же можно самостоятельно написать свой собственный почтовый агент, но это уже разработка.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Придётся значит делать кучу контактов и правила для ящиков...

Comment: @Alekcvp Да, это проще всего. В PowerShell это не представляет проблемы.

Comment: Там минус не в том что сложно, а в том что потом надо об этом постоянно помнить, когда создаёшь новых пользователей.

Comment: @Alekcvp смотря как создавать. Если руками, то да. Но пользователей можно и скриптом создавать. Тогда в скрипте можно добавить и эту логику.